# Calling mysql procedure from php with in and out paramenter

Tags: php, stored-procedures

Please help me out. I'm trying to insert the records in 2 tables, in 1st table I can insert but for the second table I can't.

I have 3 stored procedures

1. HotelInsert
2. GetAccommodationByName
3. AvailbiltyInsert

It seems like the 1st stored procedure is okay as I can get output in the first table but in the second table I can't get the last inserted id.

First stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`kno`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `HotelInsert`(IN `ZIP` BIGINT, IN `Ammn` VARCHAR(255), IN `HotelName` VARCHAR(255), IN `Add1` VARCHAR(255), IN `Add2` VARCHAR(255), IN `Det` VARCHAR(255), IN `ContactPer` VARCHAR(255), IN `Contact` VARCHAR(255), IN `CEmail` VARCHAR(255), IN `Image` VARCHAR(255), IN `StarCateg` TINYINT)
    NO SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
INSERT INTO Accommodation(
    AccommodationId,
    AccommodationTypeId,
    ZipId,
    PackageId,
    Amenities,
    Name,
    AddressOne,
    AddressTwo,
    AccommodationStatus,
    Details,
    ContactPerson,
    StarCategory,
    ImageGallery,
    ContactPhone,
    ContactEmail
)
VALUES(
    NULL,
    1,
    ZIP,
    4,
    Ammn,
    HotelName,
    Add1,
    Add2,
    1,
    Det,
    ContactPer,
    StarCateg,
    Image,
    Contact,
    CEmail
    )$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Second stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`kno`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetAccomodationIdByName`(IN `AccommodationName` VARCHAR(255), OUT `AccId` INT)
    NO SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
SELECT AccommodationId into AccId from Accommodation where Name=AccommodationName$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Third stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`kno`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AvailabilityInsert`(IN `AccId` INT, IN `RTypeId` INT, IN `AvailableRooms` INT, IN `Charges` BIGINT, IN `AvailDate` DATE)
    NO SQL
INSERT INTO AccommodationAvailabilty (AvailableId, AccommodationId, RoomTypeId, Available, Price, AvailableDate) VALUES (NULL, AccId, RTypeId, AvailableRooms, Charges, AvailDate)$$
DELIMITER ;
```

PHP code:

```
$sql = $db->prepare('CALL HotelInsert(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$sql->bind_param('dssssssssss', $ZipId, $Amenities, $Name, $AddressOne, $AddressTwo, $Details, $ContactPerson, $ContactPhone, $ContactEmail , $target_path, $StarCategory); 
$sql->execute();
$select = $db->query('SELECT @ZIP,@Ammn, @HotelName, @Add1, @Add2, @Det, @ContactPer,@Contact,@CEmail,@Image, @StarCateg');
$result = $select->fetch_assoc();
$ZipId     = $result['@ZIP'];
$Amenities = $result['@Ammn'];
$AccommodationName = $result['@HotelName'];
$AddressOne = $result['@Add1'];
$AddressTwo = $result['@Add2'];
$Details = $result['@Det'];
$ContactPerson = $result['@ContactPer'];
$ContactPhone = $result['@Contact'];
$ContactEmail = $result['@CEmail'];
$target_path = $result['@Image'];
$StarCategory = $result['@StarCateg'];


//Hotel Calling AccommodationId by AccommodationName with GetAccomodationIdByName(); stored procedure.
$sql = $db->prepare('CALL GetAccomodationIdByName(?)');
$sql->bind_param('s', $AccommodationName);
$sql->execute();
$select = $db->query('SELECT @AccId');
$result = $select->fetch_assoc();
$AccommodationId = $result['@AccId'];


//Hotel Insert RoomType by calling AvailabilityInsert(); Store procedure.

$sql = $db->prepare('CALL AvailabilityInsert(?,?,?,?,?)');
$sql->bind_param('iiids', $AccommodationId, $RoomTypeId, $Available, $Price, $AvailableDate);
$sql->execute();
$select = $db->query('SELECT  @AccId,@RTypeId, @AvailableRooms, @Charges, @AvailDate');
$result = $select->fetch_assoc();
$AccommodationId = $result['@AccId'];
$RoomTypeId = $result['@RTypeId'];
$Available = $result['@AvailableRooms'];
$Price = $result['@Charges'];
$AvailableDate = $result['@AvailDate'];


  header("Location: ../hotel-all.php?id=$Name");
  exit();
```

Comment: It would be useful to see the definitions of the stored procedures to best help you out.

Comment: @iajrz   Please see now